# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request for PUT

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have been trying to make consume an API with the PUT verb using restTemplate. I have the following code

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonString,headers);
 restTemplate.put(Url+"/'"+id,entity, String.class);
```

My `jsonString` has the following content.

```
{ 
 "id":"asdfafaff-fsf3-4b1c-a7c4-13352252daa",
 "product":"MyProductName",
 "Organization":"my company name test",
 "Organizationid":"tert122Teq-rtq-q556trt-qtqtqt3-131rtqtqt",
 "ProductProperties":"Hc2",
 "Locations":{ 
   "results":[ 

    ]
 },
 "Status":"Gone",
 "DisabledByType":null,
 "roles":null,
 "Url":"wwww.google.com",
 "Key":"xxxxxxxxxx",
 "Secret":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
 "Hash":"yyhhytyutyutuet",
 "validity":null,
 "Type":"basic",
 "Reason":null,
 "Barcodes":{ 
  "results":[ 
     "tetetetetetete"
   ]
 },
 "RelatedBarcodes":{ 
  "results":[ 

  ]
},
 "CustomizedFields":{ 
   "results":[ 

  ]
}}
```

Everything seems ok but I am receiving this error

```
HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request.
` at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:172)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:459)`
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Most likely cause is the extraneous `'` apostrophe in the URL you're building: `Url+"/'"+id`

Comment: @Andreas the url is fine. When I print it, it shows me urI would like to use.

Comment: Really? URL `http://example.com/foo/'asdfafaff-fsf3-4b1c-a7c4-13352252daa` is correct? With that dangling `'`? That's a weird API if that's true.

Comment: @Andreas I have removed it but I still have the same problem

Comment: oauth2 errors have to do with authentication. Perhaps you're missing authenication headers?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to indicate what is the exact problem when we don't know the API you're trying to consume.

HTTP status `400` means that the server was unable to process the request sent by you due to invalid syntax. It is very generic message and there may be countless reasons behind it.

You have to figure it out by yourself what exactly causes this response. You can achieve it by looking into received response's body. Since you have not declared which `ResponseErrorHandler` you want to use, the default one (`DefaultResponseErrorHandler`) has been applied. Turn on the debug mode and put some breakpoints on method `public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response)`. There you should be able to get more details from response on what went wrong and fix your request accordingly.

Comment: Even  when I put it on debug mode with breakpoints I still receive a bad request  error. I made a the same call but with a different json and to some other endpoint somewhere in my program and it works. I am really puzzle why this does not work.

Comment: Have you extracted response's body? There should be an answer to your problem, some detailed info about what went wrong.